# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.3.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, .net-4.8

My solution and projects are successfully built. When I run the main Web project, I am getting the error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Screenshot attached:

[image]

Stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider..ctor(String issuer, IEnumerable`1 keys) in /_/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt/SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider.cs:line 50
at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider..ctor(String issuer, Byte[] key) in /_/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt/SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider.cs:line 24
at A.B.Azure.AppBuilderExtensions.ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app) in ...\AppBuilderExtensions.cs:line 32
at A.B.Api.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in ...\Startup.cs:line 67
```

How did I got here?:

I updated all the Nuget packages in all my projects, especially `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`, to their latest versions - 4.2.2 and 6.22.0, respectively!

I updated all the `assemblyBinding` and `packages.config`, but can't fix it!

What am I missing here?

Comment: only thing i can think of is clearing the bin and especially the object folder of your solution, hope it helps

Comment: your solution might have multiple project with different references

Comment: @KyoshiroKokujouObscuritas Didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: @T.S. Checked and fixed all those, but still doesn't work, thanks.